# Android transparent dimmed loading screen

Tags: android, loading, spinner, transparent, wait

in this case I just wasn't sure what to look for. I have an app that queries the net for some actions, and currently the user just has to wait for those replies. What I want is a "please wait" screen, maybe even one of those hourglass/spinners, I want it overlayed on the existing screen, dimming out everything behind it

How is this done?

Can you point me to some functions or at least the proper terms to look up? I'm not sure, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about dimming the background but if you want a "Please wait..." dialog with a spinner, see this...
[ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)

EDIT: The above will also dim the background.

Comment: I am having the most difficulty getting a threaded progress dialog to behave properly. But aside from that, this is the answer I was looking for at the time. It just opened up more questions! I need a ProgressDialog that works within a thread.

Comment: @RD.: "I need a ProgressDialog that works within a thread." - It can't be done with a background/worker thread, only on the UI thread. The closest you can get is to use AsyncTask. You can create a ProgressDialog in its onPreExecute() method and dismiss it in the onPostExecute() or onCancelled() methods.

Comment: Thanks, I had to ask it again in another question because I didn't understand, but I got it working now using AsyncTask